# C2DM background technology

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I need further information about C2DM on android. The informations on http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/android/c2dm/index.html are not clear about the background technology.

Which protocolls are used? 
How does the Google server find my cell phone?

I need such informations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get some info about C2DM internals from Google I/O 2010 video: [Building push applications for Android](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PLM4LajwDVc)

Answer (score 1):

C2DM maintains an open TCP socket connection to the messaging server. Its really rather simple, other than keeping the socket open, which is no exactly trivial.