# Draining battery life by using the radio too much

Tags: android, sockets, networking, push-notification, nio

If you've been reading my questions, you'll know that I've been having a hell of a time with this app. This app includes a push service (that I wrote from scratch) and a cloud (that I wrote from scratch.) Android reports this app is using 55% of the battery. I suspect it's because the push server isn't letting the radio sleep because it's always connected.

So my question is how can I make the radio sleep and wake up when it gets something from my server? It's using java.nio - is that a potential problem? I need the async non-blocking capabilities of it. I also do not want to use Google's Cloud Messaging Service.

Specifics:
 - I'm using one socket at all times that's always connected.
 - The client doesn't send a heartbeat (none that I wrote, anyway, nio may do it by itself)
 - The server only sends things when it needs to (it uses nio as well)

Thank you for any help you can provide!

**Edit:** The radio I'm using depends on what internet connection is available. E.G. if the user has wifi on and Android connects to a network, it'll use WiFi.

Comment: Anyone wishing to roll their own push framework had better invest in a Qualcomm MDP test device, to use Trepn and determine more precisely where power drain is coming from, rather than taking random guesses. You should also consider updating your question to state specifically what radio you are trying to use (WiFi? GSM/CDMA? something else?). Also, please watch the 2010 Google I|O conference video on C2DM, where they discuss the heartbeat they used for C2DM (which later turned into GCM), as I will be surprised if you can roll a reliable push framework sans heartbeat.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6432021/1461223 What am I doing wrong here? I realize there's more to it, but why doesn't/didn't C2DM drain battery life like mine is. I wouldn't call it a random guess, I'd call it a pretty likely estimation based on a week of testing and debugging. That was the one component that was draining the battery, not the others.

Comment: "I wouldn't call it a random guess" -- based on your "55%" figure, presumably you are using the battery screen in Settings as your measuring stick. Google admits that they have no decent way of actually measuring battery consumption, and so what they record for that screen is guesswork. Buy an MDP and use Trepn.

Comment: That's where I got my first clue. It's unnatural for an app to consume 55% of the battery no matter how rough the estimate is. I did further investigation and found out more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I found where the battery consumption was via socket tagging and commenting out potentially draining behaviors. I make some heavy client optimizations and the huge drain is gone. It was mainly a CPU drain due to constantly reading from the socket when it shouldn't have been.